# Is this way of solving Thevenin theorem correct?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

This thevenin theorem is really giving me a headache, and I've really searched many sources in the internet but they confused me more and more. Take this as an [example](http://www.solved-problems.com/circuits/electrical-circuits-problems/1016/thevenins-theorem-two-independent-sources/):
[image: thevenin]

The guy in the above link says:

> The 6Ω resistor is short circuited and the 5Ω one is open. Therefore, their currents are zero and RTh=2Ω .

But see this [link](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/thevenin.html) for example and especially this picture:
[image: thevenin 2]

According to the above the $R_1$ and $R_3$ resistors should be shorted and the only one that should count is $R_2$.

And see this link [also](http://www.solved-problems.com/circuits/electrical-circuits-problems/1005/thevenins-theorem-circuit-independent-source/).

The three links solve the Thevenin theorem in different ways and especially in finding $R_{th}$ can somebody explain this to me in a simple way?

Comment: In your second case your comment that $R_2$ is the result is not correct.  The equations in the picture are right.  All of these examples are using the same strategy for finding Rth.  Perhaps you need to see the procedure outlined http://www.electricaltechnology.org/2014/01/thevenins-theorem.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both examples are using the same methods.

In the first example, the break in the circuit removes the 6 ohm and 5 ohm resistors altogether. All of the current then flows through the 2 ohm resistor, causing the Thevenin resistance to be 2 ohms.

In the second example, the current first passes through $R_2$, then is split between $R_1$ and $R_3$ in parallel. The parallel resistance between $R_1$ and $R_3$ is $\frac{R_1 R_3}{R_1 + R_3}$, and adding on the $R_2$ which is in series to both of those, we get the Thevenin resistance as $R_2 + \frac{R_1 R_3}{R_1 + R_3}$. This value is the same as the one provided by your source.

If you need any more clarification, feel free to ask in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem#Calculating_the_Th%C3%A9venin_equivalent).  There's instructions on how to calcuate $V_{th}$ and $R_{th}$.

Let $I_3$ be the current through $R_3$, $I_1$ through $R_1$, etc.

With $V_{AB}$ open, by KVL, we have $V_1 - R_1I_1 - R_3 I_3 = 0$ and $V_1 - R_1 I_1 - R_2 I_2 -V_{AB} = 0$, but when $V_{AB}$ is open we have $I_2 = 0$ and so $I_1 = I_3$, so $V_1 = (R_1 + R_3) I_1\implies\frac{V_1}{R_1 + R_3} = I_1$ and $V_1 - V_{AB} = R_1 I_1 \implies I_1 = \frac{V_1 - V_{AB}}{R_1}$.  Set the two equations equal and you get $V_{AB} = V_1( 1 - \frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_3}) = V_1(\frac{R_3}{R_1 + R_3})$.

Now according to the article I linked, **you can go about calculating $R_{th}$ in two ways**.  I'll cover the second way, that of finding $R_{th}$ by short-circuiting $V_1$.  When you do that you get $R_1 || R_3 = \frac{R_1R_3}{R_1 + R_3}$, which is then in series with $R_2$, so $R_{th} = R_2 + \frac{R_1R_3}{R_1 + R_3}$.

Hope that helps, please comment for any questions :)